# xcode 7 only shows 'iOS Device' in the simulator for the Swift 2 code downloaded from Dropbox and github

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7, swift2

And when the downloaded code is run, it comes up with this message
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Posting it here to help anyone who is facing this issue

Select the main project file at the top from Xcode.

It will navigate to a screen which has 'General', Capabilities, etc

Click on the 'Build Settings'

Select 'All'

In the search bar at the top right, search for 'iOS Deployment Target'

Its set to the latest version, eg 9.0

Change it to the least version available, say 6.0

While on this screen, try selecting the simulator from 'iOS Device' and 
you should be able to see all other simulators now. eg: iPhone 6.

Select the simulator version you want to run the code on.

Change the 'iOS Deployment Target' back to what it was, in this case 9.0